# Java Swing front-end to Etherpad

Tags: java, swing, api, http, etherpad

I am looking to implement Etherpad's functionality into a Java Swing application.  There is a Java library for accessing Etherpad's HTTP API, but it only seems to support getting/setting the entire pad text.  I want to have live multi-user editing of plain text in Java, where all users see each other's changes realtime while editing.  Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: What's wrong with [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/), or [sharing a terminal session](http://tmate.io/)?

Comment: @pieman72 I want to extend the functionality of an existing application with collaborative editing.  See http://etherpad.org/ for what I want.  I would like to use its API, but it only supports getting/setting entire documents, which is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Just use: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/SimpleSwingBrowser.java.htm and point it at the Etherpad Pad URL you want to edit...

If I'm honest though, your question is not very clear in what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Java library for easily accessing Etherpad's API.  I combined this with the JavaFX web browser component and a custom Swing UI.

For anyone finding this on Google or something, you can see my code on GitHub as a standalone app here:  https://github.com/Netsyms/SyMATPadViewer

Feel free to use it (BSD license), just change the PADS_URL in the PadUtils class and put your Etherpad API key in the file `padkey` at the root of the `src` directory.